# How to add/update a host in an inventory on Ansible Automation Platform?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to run a workflow in Ansible Automation Platform where I create an EC2 instance, then I want to add the IP to a host (or create a new host if it doesn't exist) in an inventory so that I can run playbooks/plays against that host further on in the workflow. Right now we're having AAP reach back to itself via the AAP API and update the inventory that way but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient method?

I tried using the [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) module but it looks like it only saves in memory because when I `add_host` in the first play then the second play starts running against that new host, it returns "no host matched".

In fact, even when I add the host via the API in the first play the second play doesn't find the host. It only works if they're in separate playbooks.

Is there a way to accomplish this using an existing task/module?

Comment: If you are dealing with EC2 instances, I'd recommand you looking into the dedicated dynamic inventory: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html

Comment: Where would that plugin be defined? I tried defining it (plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2) at the play level and it threw an error then I tried adding it to the variables section on the inventory and it still didn't recognize the host.

Comment: Since it is an inventory, you have to use it in an [inventory](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/09/04/how-use-dynamic-inventories-ansible-automation#prerequisites), not a playbook.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this solves my problem unfortunately

Comment: You mean that using an aws_ec2 dynamic inventory source would not solve your problem regarding dynamically adding ec2 instances? Thats weird because it is made just for that. What is not working as expected when you try using it? Note that like with any other type of inventory you may have to refresh during playbook execution using [`meta: refresh_inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html)

Comment: @Zeitounator ignore my last comment. I was worried setting up AWS as an inventory source would be more trouble than it's worth but I've been able to get it working so it looks like it will solve my problem after all. Thanks!